# mod_rewrite PHP API user resource

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, api, mod-rewrite

I am trying to create a students API endpoint for a project I am working on. The URL would be something like `https://example.com/services/student/114365` where the number at the end is the student's ID number. You would then be able to read, edit, delete, etc. the student from that endpoint.

The URL that I use now to accomplish this is `https://example.com/services/student?id=114365`. Is there a .htaccess rule I can use to convert the second URL to the first?

I apologize if this is a duplicate question. I searched SO for a good 10 minutes and couldn't find exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following rule in your htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /billing/services/student?id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

This would rewrite "billing/services/student/12345" to "billing/services/student?id=12345" , "$1"   contains the value matched inside regex pattern "([^/]+)"

Comment: I don't think it is working. I verified that my .htaccess works but the code inside doesn't seem to. It gives me a 404 not found error.  Does it matter that services/student is inside the billing folder?

Comment: How is your folder structur? and where is your htaccess file located?

Comment: /billing/services/students/index.php?id=123. The .htaccess is in students.

Answer (score 1):

General structure of rewrite rule is:

```
RewriteRule Pattern Substitution [OptionalFlags]
```

Try using following rewrite rule.

```
RewriteRule ^services/student/([^/.]+)?$ /services/student?id=$1 [L]
```

You can refer following links for more complete information regarding how to form the rewrite rules.

http://www.sitepoint.com/apache-mod_rewrite-examples/

http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite